# JS nested prototype access parent node

Tags: javascript, class, oop, instance

According to following code, I have a small problem with accessing `this` variable in prototypes.

```js
var MyClass = function(number) {
  this.number = number || 4;
};
MyClass.prototype = {
  run: function() {
    //direct access to object
    console.log(this.number);

    //access to object with the "self" object
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(self.number);
    }, 1000);

    //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
    this.events.test_a(self);

    //here is the problem
    this.events.test_b();
  },
  events: {
    test_a: function(self) {
      //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
      console.log(self.number);
    },
    test_b: function() {
      console.log(this.number); //  The problem
    }
  }
};

//----

var myClass = new MyClass(110);
myClass.run();
```

---

Is there any way to access the `this` object and having some structure like following?

```
myClass.events.test_b();
```

> I need this without using the instance that I've just created like following:

```
myClass.events.test_a(myClass);
```

Comment: @Kobe I can't see any similarity except for the mention of `this`.

Comment: It says to assign a variable with `this`, and access it that way.

Comment: @Amadan I agree, this is a diffrent construct where you have an extra level of indirection since you do `instance.something.functionThatShouldUseInstanceAsThis()` instead of `instance.functionThatShouldUseInstanceAsThis()`

Comment: @Kobe - There's no scope to do that in with the above.

Comment: I see, my bad then.

Comment: FYI, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803225/157247) (which is the accepted one) was broken. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you're best off avoiding designing the structure that way.

But you can do it by binding the `events` functions in the constructor, which means creating an "own" copy of the events object. See `***` comments in this minimal-changes version:

```js
// NOTE: Sticking to ES5 as the OP seems to be doing that

var MyClass = function(number) {
  this.number = number || 4;
  // *** Bind the functions on `this.events` to `this`
  var self = this;
  var events = self.events;
  self.events = {};
  Object.keys(events).forEach(function(key) {
    if (typeof events[key] === "function") {
      self.events[key] = events[key].bind(self);
    }
  });
};
// I've added the "name" parameter that's being passed around
// so we can be sure that the results for multiple
// instances are correct
MyClass.prototype = {
  constructor: MyClass, // *** Don't break prototype.constructor
  run: function(name) {
    //direct access to object
    console.log(name, "Direct access in object:", this.number);

    //access to object with the "self" object
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(name, "In setTimeout callback:", self.number);
    }, 1000);

    //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
    this.events.test_a(name, self);

    //here is the problem
    this.events.test_b(name);
  },
  events: {
    test_a: function(name, self) {
      //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
      console.log(name, "In test_a:", self.number);
    },
    test_b: function(name) {
      console.log(name, "In test_b:", this.number); //  Not a problem anymore
    }
  }
};

//----

var mc1 = new MyClass(110);
var mc2 = new MyClass(220);
setTimeout(function() {
    mc1.run("mc1");
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    mc2.run("mc2");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Side note: See this line I added to the object you're assigning to `prototype`:

```
constructor: MyClass, // *** Don't break prototype.constructor
```

By default, the `prototype` object on a function has a `constructor` property pointing back to the function, so best to do that.

Comment: @Thomas - Bloomin' 'eck, well-spotted. One upvote on the comment isn't sufficient. Can't believe I messed that up. I've done the ES5 version of that above (the OP seems to be using ES5-level features only).

Answer (score 2):

You can call `events.test_b` passing the context of `MyClass` instance as follows:

```
this.events.test_b.call(this);
```

```js
var MyClass = function(number) {
  this.number = number || 4;
};
MyClass.prototype = {
  run: function() {
    //direct access to object
    console.log(this.number);

    //access to object with the "self" object
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(self.number);
    }, 1000);

    //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
    this.events.test_a(self);

    //here is the problem
    this.events.test_b.call(this);
  },
  events: {
    test_a: function(self) {
      //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
      console.log(self.number);
    },
    test_b: function() {
      console.log(this.number); //  The problem
    }
  }
};

//----

var myClass = new MyClass(110);
myClass.run();
```

Comment: there's no difference between using `myClass.events.test_a(myClass);` and `myClass.events.test_b.call(myClass);` I don't want to use `myClass` object again.
So it's a good answer but not exactly what I seeking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using modern JS and arrow functions.

And maybe a transpiler for downward compatibility (if necessary)

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(number = 4) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  run() {
    //direct access to object
    console.log("run", this.number);

    // no need for "self"
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("setTimeout", this.number);
    }, 1000);

    //access to object with the "this" object as a parameter
    this.events.test_a(this);

    //here is the problem
    this.events.test_b();
  }

  events = {
    test_a: (self) => {
      //access to object with the "self" object as a parameter
      console.log("test_a", self.number);
    },

    test_b: () => {
      console.log("test_b", this.number); //  The problem
    }
  }
};

//----

var a = new MyClass(110);
a.run();
console.log("---");

var b = new MyClass(42);
b.run();
console.log("---");
```

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) may also be an alternative, as it includes the transpiler.

imo. it is unreasonable to write outdated code, just because a part of your target audiance still uses outdated browsers and you need to support them. And yes, I have clients with IE10 too and need to support down to that browser.